# Dial international number over dahdi trunk

Tags: asterisk

I am trying to perform the following outgoing call:

```
exten => _49.,1,Log(NOTICE,Dialing German number: ${EXTEN})
 same => n,Set(route=DAHDI/g1/00${EXTEN})
 same => n,Dial(${route})
exten => _0049.,1,Goto(${EXTEN:2},1)
exten => _01149.,1,Goto(${EXTEN:3},1)
exten => _+49.,1,Goto(${EXTEN:1},1)
```

But this is not working. I have also tried changing the route to:

```
 same => n,Set(route=DAHDI/g1/${EXTEN})
```

With similar results:

```
server1*CLI>
    ...
    -- Goto (ctx-carriers,491722222222,1)
    -- Executing [491722222222@ctx-carriers:1] Log("SIP/sipserver3-0000006c", "NOTICE,Dialing German number: 491722222222") in new stack
[Jul 18 07:18:53] NOTICE[19497]: Ext. 491722222222:1 @ ctx-carriers: Dialing German number: 491722222222
    -- Executing [491722222222@ctx-carriers:2] Set("SIP/sipserver3-0000006c", "route=DAHDI/g1/00491722222222") in new stack
    -- Executing [491722222222@ctx-carriers:3] Dial("SIP/sipserver3-0000006c", "DAHDI/g1/00491722222222") in new stack
    -- Called DAHDI/g1/00491722222222
    -- Hungup 'DAHDI/63-1'
  == Everyone is busy/congested at this time (1:0/0/1)
```

(the number dialed is not really `491722222222`, but a real, working mobile german number)

How can I dial international numbers via DAHDI? (in case it matters, my SS7 trunk provider is Telefonica España)

Comment: The number format looks right. Does the provider permit you to make international calls?

Comment: I am trying to verify that with my provider. Do you know of any backup solution in case I can not? I have some routing partners that I have been using for incoming calls, which I could try to contact to perform outgoing calls too, but if you have any names which are worth trying, please let me know.

Comment: There is nothign to do with asterisk. As you see it dialling. So you have check with your provider support that your dahdi card work ok and dialling format is ok. Also it MAY require correct callerid be set.